# Why does Flutter seem to instantiate the class multiple times

Tags: flutter

I have created a class to render a bottom sheet in a very typical manner seen all over the internet. However I am attempting to create a child widget to handle some logic and for some reason the child widget seems to be instantiated twice.

Take note of the print statements (print 1 thru 4) tracking the activity. When causing the code to run the output is as seen below. Everything is normal with steps 1 and 2 but 3 and 4 are repeated twice. This sucks because after the internet connection is re-established it makes duplicate calls to whatever action is setup, this particular action is an api call.

So in short, everything seems good until the ConnectManagerContent widget is instantiated. I cannot understand why this is happening twice when the caller is only called once.

Thanks in advance.

```
flutter: 1 SETUP ======== 
flutter: 2 SETUP ========

flutter: 3 SETUP ========
flutter: 1234
flutter: 3 SETUP ========

flutter: 4 SETUP ========   

flutter: 3 SETUP ========   
flutter: 1234 
flutter: 3 SETUP ========

flutter: 4 SETUP ========
```

***Widget calling Bottom Sheet Class:***

```
if (isCennectionError(state.error)) {
 
  print("1 SETUP ========");

  ConnectManager(
    id: "1234",
    context: context,
    connectBloc: connectionBloc,
    onVisible: handleErrorVisible,
    onConnect: () {
      context.read<MediasBloc>().add(
            UpdateMedia(
              id: widget.media.id!,
              className: className,
              data: {
                "title": mediaTitleFieldController.text,
                "description": mediaDescFieldController.text
              },
            ),
          );

      handleErrorDismiss();
    },
  ).showConnectManager();

  return;
}
```

***Bottom Sheet Class***

```
class ConnectManager {
  late BuildContext context;
  final ConnectBloc connectBloc;
  final Function onVisible;
  final Function onConnect;
  final String? id;

  ConnectManager({
    required this.context,
    required this.connectBloc,
    required this.onVisible,
    required this.onConnect,
    this.id,
  });

  Future<void> showConnectManager() async {

    print("2 SETUP ========");

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: colorWhite, width: 3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
          ),
        ),
        onVisible: () {
          onVisible();
        },
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 10000),
        backgroundColor: colorPrimary,
        content: ConnectManagerContent(
          id: id,
          currentContext: context,
          message: dioInternetConnectionRequired,
          onConnect: onConnect,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Bottom Sheet Content Widget Class***

```
class ConnectManagerContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext currentContext;
  final String message;
  final Function onConnect;
  final String? id;

  const ConnectManagerContent({
    super.key,
    required this.currentContext,
    required this.message,
    required this.onConnect,
    this.id,
  });

  @override
  State<ConnectManagerContent> createState() => _ConnectManagerContentState();
}

class _ConnectManagerContentState extends State<ConnectManagerContent> {
  final Debouncer debouncer = Debouncer();

  bool connected = false;

  late final Timer timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 
    print("3 SETUP ========");
    print(widget.id);
    print("3 SETUP ========");

    init();
  }

  Future checkInternetConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup("google.com");

      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  }

  void init() {
    
    print("4 SETUP ========");

    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      (timer) {
        checkInternetConnection().then(
          (value) {
            if (value) {
              timer.cancel();

              widget.onConnect();

              ScaffoldMessenger.of(widget.currentContext).hideCurrentSnackBar();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                widget.message,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  height: 1.3,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        const Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [Text("Checking...")],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you put the ConnectManagerContent? If you don't use setState or any builder where ConnectManagerContent is used there, that's very odd

Comment: I put it where the content property is on the SnackBar widget. According to the docs that can be a Widget. I think what your saying is the SnackBar is on a function and there's no builder? Yes this is a pattern I found on the internet.